# Do I need to duplicate the CSS Transition statement?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I was reading the mozilla developer docs for CSS Transitions.  In their [simple example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#A_simple_example), they put the transition statement on the element and the pseudo-class "hover".

```
#delay1 {
  position: relative;
  transition-property: font-size;
  transition-duration: 4s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#delay1:hover {
  transition-property: font-size;
  transition-duration: 4s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

Is it necessary to put the transition statement on the pseudo-class "hover" as well as the main element?  Is it best practice?  In my experience, I've only had to put the statement on the element to get the desired behavior.  See example: http://jsfiddle.net/z6v9do82/

Comment: **put the statement on the element to get the desired behavior** that's the way to go. Maybe one case to put it also on the `:hover` state (not pseudo-element) is change some properties like the duration or delay.

Comment: I don't see why you need to put it on the hover if none of the animation is changing

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z6v9do82/1/

Comment: Thank you @DanielPinzon for the feedback.  That is a good point you make about changing the transition.  I do not plan on changing the transition or any of it's properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it's redundant to specify the transition again on `:hover` since you've already specified it on the more general rule. `transition` works exactly like any other property in that regard. It's not clear whether that example has the declarations repeated in both rules for illustrative purposes, or if it's simply a mistake.

On an interesting note, if you specify the transition *only* on `:hover` and not the general, stateless rule:

```
#delay1 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#delay1:hover {
  transition: font-size 4s 2s;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

What happens is that the animation takes effect once the element starts matching `:hover`, but not when the element stops matching it. To get the opposite effect, i.e. only animate when the element stops matching `:hover`, you'd need to specify the transition on `:not(:hover)`:

```
#delay1 {
  transition: font-size 4s 2s;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#delay1:hover {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

Note that `#delay1` is not the same as `#delay1:not(:hover)` because the former matches *regardless* of an element's hover state; it is essentially a union of both `#delay1:not(:hover)` *and* `#delay1:hover` (the two of which are mutually exclusive to each other).

Comment: @bheussler: I've removed that bit now since it's obsolete. I also added some supplementary information.